# How to center-align text, above button

Tags: html, css

I want to have a button with a text, but I want to place another text right above it aligned center. Here is a pseudo demo to show up what I want:

[image]

Each button `OFF` and `Next` have associated text respectively `Text over OffButton` and `Text over NextButton`. I am not speaking about the default button text( in this case `OFF` and `Next`) but for the text right above them. Namely `Text over OffButton` and `Text over NextButton`

Comment: wrap everything inside a div and `text-align:center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each button and text in a div and center align it like so.

```css
.button-wrapper {text-align:center;display:inline-block; margin:10px;}
button {padding:10px; background-color:green;color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
<p>Text over button 1</p>
<button type="button">Click here</button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
<p>Text over button 2</p>
<button type="button">Click here</button>
</div>
```